# function of class definition in source file v.s. inline functions

Tags: c++, refactoring, inline

I am refactoring a big legacy source file "big.cpp", which contains several class definitions, used solely in this file. e.g., in big.cpp

```
class A {
  inline void func1() {
    // bla bla ...
  }
  void func2() {
    // bla bla ...
  }
}
```

some functions are explicitly with in-line keyword, some are not.

As these classes are only in cpp file, not even in header file, it is quite a mess and not possible to unit test, etc. so I am trying to split it into smaller files, as "a.h", "a.cpp"; Then I have a concern. after refactoring, shall these functions be treated as inline functions or not? e.g., I guess func1() shall be inlined, but what about func2()?

I am afraid, if some former inline functions are changed to non-inline, their performance will be slower, so I have to be careful.

Comment: Whether the non inline functions have an impact on performance is not obvious, difference may be negligible. I would carry on with refactoring.

Comment: yeah, as this code is quite sensitive, I have to play safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a member function inside a class like `func2` in your example, the `inline` is implied.

Comment: then in this case, all the functions are actually "inline". so there is no way to refactor it without changing the performance.

Comment: @pepero The `inline` keyword (explicit or implicit) is just a *hint* for the compiler, it's up to the compiler to actually inline the calls. And it might even inline functions that are *not* marked `inline`. And if you measure I doubt you'll find much of a noticeable difference between an inline and a non-inline function these days.

Comment: thanks, then I am relieved for this concern.